# Automapper Composite DTO to ViewModel conversion

Tags: c#, automapper

In some cases there is a need to return composite DTOs from our repository, where the DTO just has a few properties that are Model properties and the function of the DTO is just to be a simple composite object (returning a Queryable is not enough because there is more information than T)

For example:

Model:

```
public class Job
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties
}

public class JobApplication
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties
}
```

Repository:
    `IQueryable<JobAndUserApplication>  GetJobAndMatchingUserApplication(int userId)`:

```
public class JobAndUserApplication
{
    public Job Job { get; set; }
    public JobApplication JobApplication { get; set; }
}
```

Now - Id like to simply do (Project and To are Automapper functionality):

```
//this allows one efficient query to bring in the subproperties of the composite DTO    
var jobVmList = jobRepository.GetAllJobsAndMatchingJobApplicationByUser(userId)              
                             .Project()
                             .To<JobVM>()
                             .ToList();
```

So I need a mapping kind of like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<JobAndUserApplication, JobVM>()
      .ForMember(jvm => jvm, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Job));
      //many other .ForMembers that are not relevant right now
```

I am attempting to map the Job property of the DTO directly on to the JobVM (which shares many of the same properties).

My mapping throws the following exception:

Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish the mapping form the Job property of the DTO on the the JobVM itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automapper is telling you that you can only define custom actions on a member (property) of a class, not on the class itself. What you need to do is first create a Job to JobVM map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobVM>()
```

and

```
Mapper.CreateMap<JobAndUserApplication, JobVM>()
```

being sure to ignore and set any duplicate properties across the two types. Then run automapper twice, first from the child object:

```
var jobVM = Mapper.Map<Job, JobVM>(jobAndUserApplication.job);
```

then from the parent object

```
Mapper.Map<JobAndUserApplication, JobVM>(jobAndUserApplication, jobVM );
```

Or the other way around, depending on how your properties are laid out.

Quick side note: I have a feeling you might be mixing concerns, and my code smell alarm is going off. I'd take a second look at either your viewmodel or domain model, as this is not a typical issue I see come up. (just my $0.02 :-)

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I was trying to avoid calling the Map method twice - not that it's a huge deal but I thought that AutoMapper with its rich configuration should surely be able to allow me to configure the mapping such that I only need to call Map once.  I'll respond to the code smell in a different comment.

Comment: Our repositories only return Models and our service layers operate on the repositories and return DTOs.  Calling multiple repository methods in the services to glue the returned results together are an unnecessary performance problem (multiple queries and unnecessary in-memory processing that a database does well).  There is no other way that I know of than using a composite class (that just glues two Models together) to return Models in order to run a single select efficient query that doesn't have to do in memory processing.  This is because AFAIK Automapper can't process anonymous types.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Another approach you can take is to setup custom mapping logic is in .AfterMap() You use anonymous functions to define custom mapping logic which can help you avoid the second call.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I have tried all of these and they won't work:  
-`.AfterMap((jaua, jvm) => { Mapper.Map<Job, JobVM>(jaua.Job, jvm);});`  
-`.ConstructUsing(jaua => { Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobVM>(); return Mapper.Map<Job, JobVM>(jaua.Job); });`  
-`.ConvertUsing( jaua => {return Mapper.Map<Job, JobVM>(jaua.Job, new JobVM()); });`  
-`.ForMember(jvm => jvm, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Job));`

Comment: I uploaded an automapper POC that I created months ago. Maybe you can fork it and put more detail in there about the problems you are having? My guess is there is something missing that I'm not seeing in the question. https://github.com/JasonMore/AutoMapper-Ioc-Example

Comment: I'll try to do that, but basically it seems none of the extension methods such as AfterMap, ConstructUsing, ConvertUsing, etc., can successfully map class properties of a source on to the actual class of the destination itself.  As you said, it has to be a property of the destination class. I try running Map on a dynamically created instance of the destination type inside of ConstructUsing or ConvertUsing but to no avail...  For example:  .ConstructUsing(jaua => { Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobVM>(); return Mapper.Map<Job, JobVM>(jaua.Job); });  Shouldn't that work???

Comment: Ah, what I meant with after map is that you won't get to use any automapper magic, but instead doing it by hand.